# Powershell ImportExcel module giving error

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I am using below code to get value of cell A1 but it's gives me error like that
Code:

```
$excelpath = "G:\Fiverr Work\Final_result.xlsx"
$MyExcelFile = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $excelpath
$importedExcelRows = Import-Excel -Path $excelpath
$RowCount=$($importedExcelRows.Count)
$MyExcelWorksheet = $MyExcelFile.Workbook.Worksheets['items']
$a1='A'+ 1
$valuefromexcel=$worksheet.Cells($a1).Value
```

Error:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At G:\Fiverr Work\powershell import excel module.ps1:7 char:1

- $valuefromexcel=$worksheet.Cells($a1).Value

Comment: From your sample. you don't have a `$worksheet` variable declared, only a `$MyExcelWorksheet` ... So I think you just need to replace the former by the latter and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing and matching ideas.

`Import-Excel $excelPath` will open the file, and try to read all the data from the first sheet. If your data is shaped like a table, starts in row 1, col 1, and the first row has the column names, `Import-Excel` will return an array of objects and use the first row as property names.

`Open-ExcelPackage` gives you full access to the Excel object model of the target file.

Something along these lines ought to give you a starting point.

```
$excelpath = "G:\Fiverr Work\Final_result.xlsx"
$MyExcelFile = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $excelpath
$MyExcelWorksheet = $MyExcelFile.Workbook.Worksheets['items']
$MyExcelWorksheet.Cells['A1'].Value
Close-ExcelPackage $MyExcelFile -NoSave
```